# How do I persuade IIS to deliver content from within a Zip file?

Tags: iis, compression, isapi

Is it possible to "persuade" IIS to deliver content from a Zip file "Container" ? For example I have lots of PDF documents packed in Zip archives and I need to display the PDFs in a browser. So for example if the Zip file is named "Container.zip" and one of the PDFs in the Container,zip is called "test.pdf" I want to retrieve the  test PDF with a URL of the form:

http://myhost.domain.local/getfromzip.dll?container.zip&test.pdf

I guess one could write such an isapi Module but maybe something like this already exists ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that there is no Standard module available, so I made a simple Delphi ISAPI module as a POC. Works fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

It is called "Programming". No functionality ouf of the box. It is a nice thing to do, though - years ago we did do that with zip files contianing html based documentation. TONS of small files, a lot easier to just replace a zip than handle a folder upload with 50.000 or more elements.

Comment: yes, I just dd this but didn't want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Why ISAPI? We did the same with ASP.NET nearly 15 years ago and it worked fine ;) No need to go native.

Comment: Writing an isapi dll is ten lines of code (for this POC) with Delphi: